# How to convert timezone to country code in Python?

Tags: python, timezone, country-codes

I used this

```
from pytz import country_timezones
```

But It doesn't include below timezones

> Africa/Asmera, Africa/Timbuktu, America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia, America/Atka, America/Buenos_Aires, America/Catamarca, America/Coral_Harbour, America/Cordoba, America/Ensenada, America/Fort_Wayne, America/Indianapolis, America/Jujuy, America/Knox_IN, America/Louisville, America/Mendoza, America/Montreal, America/Porto_Acre, America/Rosario, America/Shiprock, America/Virgin, Antarctica/South_Pole, Asia/Ashkhabad, Asia/Calcutta, Asia/Chongqing, Asia/Chungking, Asia/Dacca, Asia/Harbin, Asia/Istanbul, Asia/Kashgar, Asia/Katmandu, Asia/Macao, Asia/Saigon, Asia/Tel_Aviv, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Asia/Ulan_Bator, Atlantic/Faeroe, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, Australia/ACT, Australia/Canberra, Australia/LHI, Australia/NSW, Australia/North, Australia/Queensland, Australia/South, Australia/Tasmania, Australia/Victoria, Australia/West, Australia/Yancowinna, Brazil/Acre, Brazil/DeNoronha, Brazil/East, Brazil/West, CET, CST6CDT, Canada/Atlantic, Canada/Central, Canada/East-Saskatchewan, Canada/Eastern, Canada/Mountain, Canada/Newfoundland, Canada/Pacific, Canada/Saskatchewan, Canada/Yukon, Chile/Continental, Chile/EasterIsland, Cuba, EET, EST, EST5EDT, Egypt, Eire, Europe/Belfast, Europe/Nicosia, Europe/Tiraspol, GB, GB-Eire, Greenwich, HST, Hongkong, Iceland, Iran, Israel, Jamaica, Japan, Kwajalein, Libya, MET, MST, MST7MDT, Mexico/BajaNorte, Mexico/BajaSur, Mexico/General, NZ, NZ-CHAT, Navajo, PRC, PST8PDT, Pacific/Ponape, Pacific/Samoa, Pacific/Truk, Pacific/Yap, Poland, Portugal, ROC, ROK, Singapore, Turkey, UCT, US/Alaska, US/Aleutian, US/Arizona, US/Central, US/East-Indiana, US/Eastern, US/Hawaii, US/Indiana-Starke, US/Michigan, US/Mountain, US/Pacific, US/Samoa, UTC, Universal, W-SU, WET, Zulu

How can I convert these timezones to country code?

Comment: Many countries can have the same timezone, I don't think you can convert a timezone to a country code just like that

Comment: I know, I just want to figure out that except kind of multi-area's timezone. like "Asia/Macao"

Comment: @Morb Also, if you're in Russia or the U.S. for example, the opposite can be true: Many timezones in one country

Comment: True. I guess there are some libs out there that can help you

Comment: All of those timezones are either deprecated or historical timezones. Some are specified as links to current timezones in the Olson database, others as unique timezones that just aren't in use anymore, and I think some aren't even in the database at all. But regardless, they're not in use by any country, and therefore what you're asking for is impossible: you can't get "the country that uses Zulu" if no country uses Zulu.

Comment: Removed line breaks to prevent massive scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want. Or, you can, but you'll get the results you're getting, not the results you want. Briefly, if you ask for "the country that uses Zulu", and no country uses Zulu, you won't be able to find anything. In more detail…

---

As the docs on [Country Information](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#country-information) say:

> A mechanism is provided to access the timezones commonly in use for a particular country, looked up using the ISO 3166 country code.

---

However, "deprecated" zones like `America/Buenos_Aires` and "historical" zones like `US/Pacific` aren't in use in any particular country. Many of them *do* happen to be aliases for timezones that *are* in use in some country, like `America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires` and `America/Los_Angeles`, respectively, but that doesn't do you any good, because `pytz` doesn't expose that information. You could file an enhancement request against `pytz` to add that in a future version, if you think it's important.

---

At any rate, this is how you can identify the countries that use a given timezone, like this:

```
{country for country, timezones in country_timezones.items()
 if timezone in timezones}
```

---

If you need to do lots of these lookups, you can of course build your own dict to make it faster and simpler:

```
timezone_countries = {}
for country, timezones in country_timezones.items():
    for timezone in timezones:
        timezone_countries.setdefault(timezone, set()).add(country)
```

And now it's just:

```
timezone_countries[timezone]
```

---

But either way, you may get an empty set, or a set of 3 countries, instead of 1. If the database actually says that there are 0 or 3 countries that use that timezone, that's what you're going to get.